# grant_type is required error invalid_request

Tags: javascript, post, oauth-2.0, postman, request-headers

I always got "grant_type is required error invalid_request" with the following JS script and I have not idea why:

```
let tokenUrl = 'myTokenURL';
let clientId = 'myClientID';
let clientSecret = 'myClientSecret';
let scope = 'myScope';

let getTokenRequest = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: tokenUrl,
    auth: {
        type: "basic",
        basic: [
            { key: "username", value: clientId },
            { key: "password", value: clientSecret }
        ]
    },
    header: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: {
        mode: 'formdata',
        formdata: [
            { key: "grant_type", value: "authorization_code" },
            { key: 'scope', value: scope },
            { key: 'redirect_uri', value: 'MyRedirectURI' },
            { key: 'client_id', value: clientId},
            { key: 'clientSecret', value: clientSecret},
        ]
    }
};


pm.sendRequest(getTokenRequest, (err, response) => {
    let jsonResponse = jsonResponse = response.json();;    
    let newAccessToken = jsonResponse.access_token;

    console.log({ err, jsonResponse, newAccessToken })
});
```

this is using Postman sendRequest function

Comment: Wouldn't the `mode` be 'urlencoded' if you're using that header and that would also be the key for the array?

Comment: @DannyDainton thanks a lot, that's the answer that I'm looking for ;)

Answer (score 0):

For those all the people interested in the solution for this, please see the following code which practically it is the Danny Daiton's answer in the above comments

```
let tokenUrl = 'myTokenURL';
let clientId = 'myClientID';
let clientSecret = 'myClientSecret';
let scope = 'myScope';

let getTokenRequest = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: tokenUrl,
    auth: {
        type: "basic",
        basic: [
            { key: "username", value: clientId },
            { key: "password", value: clientSecret }
        ]
    },
    header: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: {
        mode: 'urlencoded',
        urlencoded: [
            { key: "grant_type", value: "authorization_code" },
            { key: 'scope', value: scope },
            { key: 'redirect_uri', value: 'MyRedirectURI' },
            { key: 'client_id', value: clientId},
            { key: 'clientSecret', value: clientSecret},
        ]
    }
};


pm.sendRequest(getTokenRequest, (err, response) => {
    let jsonResponse = jsonResponse = response.json();;    
    let newAccessToken = jsonResponse.access_token;

    console.log({ err, jsonResponse, newAccessToken })
});
```